# Boolean algebra and existence of meets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, boolean-algebra

I have a set of sets S that is closed under the set-theoretic operations of union, intersection, and complement, so it basically forms a Boolean algebra with the join operator being union, the meet operator being intersection, and the complement operator being set complement.

Then, I have three subsets A, B, and C of set S.

I know that if A $\subseteq$ B and A $\subseteq$ C then A $\subseteq$ B $\cap$ C.

I do not want to prove that property/law, I just want to use it in my manuscript, but does it have a name?

I found in wikipedia that it is called "existence of meets" ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets)), so is it correct if I say that "As A $\subseteq$ B and A $\subseteq$ C, it holds that A $\subseteq$ B $\cap$ C by existence of meets." or is there a better suggestion?

Comment: What you're using is not just that the meet of $B$ and $C$ exists but that it is the intersection $B\cap C$.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it is already known that the meet operator is the set intersection because my set forms a Boolean algebra, I just want to know how to properly reference the property that if A ⊆ B and A ⊆ C then A ⊆ B ∩ C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to show:

$P$. If A $\subseteq$ B and A $\subseteq$ C, then A $\subseteq$ B $\cap$ C

is not *by* the existence of meets, but this is rather (part of) what the existence of meets *means*.  So, you can *refer* to this result *as* (part of) the existence of meets, but you don't use the existence of meets to justify or prove $P$.  To prove $P$, you would presumably just use the basic definitions of $\subseteq$ and $\cap$.